# Sublime Text 3 - Plugin Profiles

Tags: java, python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am currently using Sublime Text 3 for programming in Python, Java, C++ and HTML. So, for each language I have a different set of plugins. I would like to know if there is a way for changing between "profiles", with each profile containing plugins of the respective language. My PC is not all that powerful, so it starts to hang if I have too many active plugins. So when one profile is running, all other plugins should be disabled.

**TL;DR :** Is there a way to change between "profiles" containing a different set of plugins in Sublime Text?

Comment: How many plugins are you using? I don't think I've ever seen Sublime use more than 2% of my CPU with ~15 plugins.

Comment: I've got around 10 for each. But as I said, the PC is really slow/old and struggles to open even windows explorer while using ST3

Comment: One thing you might be able to try (some quick googling inspired this) is to create a separate plugins folder for each profile, then use a batch script (you said Windows) to rename the folders and change which one is being used. Then, you could just run something like `subl_use_profile.bat Python` or `subl_use_profile.bat HTML`.

Comment: Hmmm I shall try that. So you're saying that I should make a bat script that changes the name of the plugins folder for each program

Comment: It's pretty hacky, and I wouldn't *really* recommend doing it, but it could work. There's no harm in trying. Wel... as long as you don't mess up your command...

Comment: I'm suprised no one else has come across this problem yet. I thought there would be some easy solution. BTW, why was this downvoted?

Comment: Are you sure it's Sublime Text which is causing this lag? Open Task Manager and see if any other applications/processes are running.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. My computer runs normally when closed. Oh, and I'm running it on a portable USB version.

Comment: I have been looking for this feature as well :)

I would like per "user profile" (environment) to have different settings, themes, plugins, etc...

I have already upvoted your question as well this post: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/141678-users-profiles/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of doing this on Windows is to have multiple portable installs, each one set up for your programming language and plugin set of your choice. You can then set up multiple icons on your desktop/taskbar/start menu/whatever, each one pointing to a different installation. This way you don't have to mess around with writing batch files to rename things.

Alternatively, you could just spring for a new computer :)

Comment: I guess that's the best option. But I'm surprised no one has come across this problem yet....

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB typically Sublime is really good with memory and plugin management, so maybe your computer is just so lousy (no offense) or there are other issues with Windows that it'll run slowly no matter what. Perhaps one or more of your plugins has a memory leak, or is running an `EventListener` after every keystroke (linters will do that), or something else is going on that is slowing everything down. There are a ton of reasons for why this could be happening, and you may just be in a perfect storm of many of them.

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB everyone diminishes this feature, I do not understand why... and the ones who try to contribute with ideas, propose DIY solutions like bash or batch scripts... IMHO they are not optimal solutions...

Comment: Yes; I still haven't found an optimal solution. I'm surprised this hasn't attracted attention yet....

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB if you'd like to submit a new feature request, just go to https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues and explain in detail what kind of functionality you're looking for. Of course, there are no guarantees that it will be implemented, but Sublime's author Jon Skinner is aware of the issue tracker and takes it into account. You can also use the same site for reporting bugs with the ST3 core, or https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/DefaultPackages/issues for problems with Sublime's default packages.

Comment: ST ecosystem already uses a platform for request submit by the users, it's http://sublimetext.userecho.com/

And unfortunatly there is a request for this feature that @WhiteFlameAB asked but submitted by someone else:
http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/141678-users-profiles/

Comment: @PauloOliveira the Github "repos" (they don't hold any files, just issues) are now the central repository for bugs and enhancement requests, combining random untracked threads on the [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) and a good portion of userecho. The Github effort, which Jon is fully behind, is coordinated by a core group of Sublime developers and power users (myself included) who actually give feedback, help troubleshoot, and prioritize things. If you still want to submit or vote on userecho I'm not going to stop you, I'm just not sure how relevant it is anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo I will follow your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 if you delete this folder -->    *C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3*

then sublime text will default back to its original state. Maybe if you setup a batch file to keep different versions of this folder for example":

*"./Sublime Text 3_Java"* or

*"./Sublime Text 3_Python"* or

*"./Sublime Text 3_C++"*

and then when you want to work on java have a batch file to rename *"./Sublime Text 3_Java"* to *"./Sublime Text 3"* and restart sublime. If you really want to get fancy use a symlink to represent *"./Sublime Text 3"* then have the batch file to modify(or delete and recreate) where the symlink points to.